# How to Search the Files in Linux with a List of Return Data from Another Command

Tags: regex, bash, awk, grep

I'm trying to search the content of all the files in directory B which might contain a string that matches a list of file names from another directory (a).

For instance, if directory `a` contains a list of files that their content either contains `STR1` or `STR2`, I can get a list the name of the files (minus the type) with:

```
cd /dir/a/ && grep 'STR1\|STR2' * | awk -F. '{print $1}' | uniq -u
```

which produces something like:

```
filename1
filename7
filename13
filename24
```

Now, I need to get the list outputted by this command (first column, e.g. filename1, filename7, etc.), and search the content of each file in `/dir/b/*` to see if any of item in the list is available in the list above. If I try this:

```
grep $(grep 'STR1\|STR2' /dir/a/* | awk -F. '{print $1}' | uniq -u) /dir/b/*
```

I get multiple `grep somestr_from_command: no such file or directory`, and only one of the items from the list is searched for availability in `/dir/b/` files.

How can I transform the output of `grep 'STR1\|STR2' * | awk -F. '{print $1}' | uniq -u` to something like `grep 'filename1|filename7|filename13|filename24' …` so I can be fed to the outermost `grep`?

Comment: `grep -l` would give you the filenames directly, no need for `awk` or `uniq`.

Comment: I am doing `cd`ing into the `/dir/b` first, so need to have an absolute path to `/dir/a`, therefore, the inner most `grep` with `-l` and without `sed` would print out the absolute path of the files in `/dir/a`. The `awk` is needed to remove the file type as I mentioned (`minus the type`).

Comment: I'm talking about: `cd /dir/a/ && grep 'STR1\|STR2' * | awk -F. '{print $1}' | uniq -u` where you _wont_ get the absolute path. Ok, you strip away everything after the first `.` in the filename so `foo.bar.ext` will become `foo`. It's still a lot of extra parsing and `grep -l ... * | ...` would jump to the next file on first hit in a file. You parse through the whole file.

Comment: If I do an absolute path to `/dir/b/*`, I get `-bash: /bin/grep: Argument list too long` for some reason. Hence the reason I `cd` first into the final directory, then run the command. Besides, this is not addressing the issue but attempting to optimize the process. I'm not sure why you are focusing on this matter.

Comment: It's minor details perhaps but may nevertheless make it easier for you, that's why I bother. I didn't say anything about _not_ doing `cd`. I'm just saying that you don't get the absolute path with your `grep ... * | awk | uniq` so `grep -l` will only make it faster.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Removed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `-f` option in `grep` with a process substitution for another command:

```
grep -Ff <(awk '/str1|str2/{s=FILENAME; gsub(/^.+\/|\.[^.]+$/, "", s); print s; nextfile}' /dir/a*) /dir/b*
```

Also note that a single `awk` command can replace `grep | awk | uniq` pipeline.

Comment: The problem is, the following `awk '/str1|str2/{s=FILENAME; sub(/\..+$/, "", s); print s; nextfile}' /dir/a/*.txt` would output a list of files like `/dir/a/filename3` or `/dir/a/filename7`, which will not match the content of the file for searching in `/dir/b/*`. I need to search for `filename3` or `filename7` only. And most importantly, it outputs it per line, so not sure how the outer `grep` is going to like that. It's similar to what I have in the question which is not working.

Comment: ok check updated command. Having filename one per line is required in using `<(...)` with `-f` option.

Comment: It did the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something along these lines:

```
for fn in *; do 
    if [ -f "$fn" ]; then
        awk ' /STR1|STR2/{ split(FILENAME,f,"\\."); print f[1]; nextfile}' "$fn"
    fi          
done
```